# Dc Motor circuit

Tags: motor, 555

I am making a motor control circuit for my model plane engine.

It has to start slowly and climb to its full power and stop slowly like a jet engine fan.

I saw a video on YouTube called 'super capacitor on a motor', where a capacitor is mounted on a DC motor and connected to a battery.

When the circuit is on, the motor slowly turns; when capacitor is charged, the motor goes to full power.

When the circuit is closed, the motor still turns and slowly dies out.

What is the science behind it? I want a motor control circuit and its graph.

Answer (score 2):

It very simple.

[image]

Initially the supercap is totally discharged (0V). When the motor is switched ON a large current flows charging up the supercap. The capacitor acts like a short circuit meaning there is no any voltage between the terminals of motor(and capacitor of course). The maximum current is limited by the internal resistance of the battery.

As the supcap charges up it takes less and less current so the voltage across the capacitor(and motor) terminals rises (first part of graph). The motor can then start to turn and as the voltage increases the motor turns faster and faster.

Once the capacitor is charged it takes no more current and the voltage across the motor is the voltage from the battery, V (less a small drop across the internal resistance). (mid section of graph)

When the switch is opened the battery is disconnected. The charged supercap then discharges through the motor causing it to reduce speed over time. (last section of graph).

Comment: Could this be a double-pole situation? You've pointed out one pole (RC), but the motor *itself* is another pole, storing mechanical energy (a simile to a capacitor storing energy). Perhaps it depends on what you regard as "output".

Answer (score 1):

This is a really simple mathematical equation.

$$t=R*C$$

C is the capacity of your capacitor where R is the Resistor which loads the capacitor. t is the time constant tau. Tau gives you the time, the supply needs to charge the capacitor to up to 63% of its capacity. its an e-curve. so nearly 100% is achieved after about $$ 5 * t $$

In your case, R is determined by the inner resistance of your DC-Power Supply. You can calculate this resistor by measuring the shortsircuit current of your supply.

This is the corresponding graph for charhing and discharging your cap. 
[image]